# Feedback form on Drupal 6 CCK content type

Tags: drupal, cck

This is a follow on to my previous question [Creating Drupal CCK content programatically/ via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772880/creating-drupal-cck-content-programatically-via-api) which is now pretty much complete.

I have a system in Drupal 6 which uses the CCK quite extensively and generates exercise programmes for users based on their preferences.  The programmes are Content Types made up from mainly other content types (exercises, equipment) and makes extensive use of taxonomy.  What I would like to do is provide the user the option to give feedback on a programme which can then be taken into account during the generation of any subsequent programmes.  Ideally a user will be able to visit a page which lists the exercises from a programme with a rating against each, and a couple of feedback boxes.

I'm about to crack on with developing this as a custom module using the Forms API however before doing this wondered if there was a better / simpler approach that could be acheived with the CCK and additional modules?  Is a custom module approach the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the fivestar module?  You could use that to allow users to vote on the exercises, assuming the exercises are nodes.  At the least, the votingapi should be used as the basis of any vote-related feedback, I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using the core Comments module to capture feedback?

Comment: I have looked at this - I need to capture slightly more structured feedback to determine whether exercises are used / not used in subsequent programs.  This will work for the human readable feedback but I'm not sure about the score for each exercise

Comment: Fair enough.  I think a combination of Comments + something like Fivestar (like John suggested earlier) might be the way to go.  There's also the Flag module which would let your users indicate "I found this useful" or "Like" (or anything you want) for each exercise.